# Excel calculate MAX From aggregated SUM

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of values associated with timestamps across multiple dates:

| Timestamp (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm) | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2021/01/01 08:12 | 3 |
| 2021/01/01 09:12 | 2 |
| 2021/01/01 11:30 | 5 |
| 2021/01/01 14:08 | 4 |
| 2021/01/02 09:12 | 3 |
| 2021/01/02 10:45 | 4 |
| 2021/01/02 12:12 | 6 |
| 2021/01/03 09:12 | 2 |
| 2021/01/03 10:45 | 8 |
| 2021/01/03 15:32 | 7 |

How do I calculate the the MAX sum of values aggregated by the day?

In the given example, the sums for each day would be:

```
2021/01/01  14
2021/01/02  13
2021/01/03  17
```

And I would like to calculate this value: `2021/01/03  17`

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

As Scott Craner suggested, you may use the Pivot Table.

Then please use **Filter** to shown the **MAX value**.

**Steps**

- I created a similar sample as yours, then I select the data range and right click it, choose "Get Data from Table/Range···" to import these data to Power Query.
- And then I choose the colum "Timestamp (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm)", go to
  Transform tab > Date & Time Column group > Date, choose Date Only.
- I load it to one worksheet, and modify one column name form
  "Timestamp (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm)" to "Timestamp". Then I insert a pivot
  table as the following image, which is like your result.

[image]

- After creating the pivot table, I click the Filter button beside "Row Labels", go to Values Filters > Top 10···, choose **Top 1** as the screenshot below shown.

[image]

- At last, the pivot table show the filter result.

[image]

Comment: I've been looking at a few of your answers.  I believe that I have reasonably good (i.e., at least average) eyesight, and I have some difficulty understanding your illustrations, especially the animated ones.  I can only imagine that it's even harder for people with vision impairments. (Yes, blind people use computers, and they use Super User.)  Stack Exchange [discourages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052) the over-use of images.  As much as possible, you should say what you mean *with words* (i.e., provide instructions), and use images to ***illustrate*** your posts.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for your kind suggestions, and I have edited my previous answer.